NGINX prefix match does not work as expected
I'm trying to set up an application staging server with NGINX. With this configuration, a single machine will act as a Keycloak authentication server, REST API server, and web UI server.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <my-private-ip>;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/<my-private-ip>.access.log;
    
    location /keycloak {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }

    location /wms-ui {
        alias /var/www/<my-private-ip>/html/wms-ui;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /wms-api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite / /wms-ui;
    }
}

My UI is a React SPA that uses react-router-dom. I'm serving it under location "/wms-ui", but I'm running into 404 errors when accessing anything other than the "root" route. Meaning, if I go to http://<my-private-ip>/wms-ui I get to my "dashboard" page, and navigating inside the app works fine because that's handled by react-router-dom. But if I try to access http://<my-private-ip>/wms-ui/some-other-page directly I get an NGINX default 404 error.

My understanding is that a request to any location that starts with /wms-ui should match location /wms-ui, which serves a file called index.html located at /var/www/<my-private-ip>/html/wms-ui, but that's not what's happening.
I tried changing location /wms-ui to location ~ ^/wms-ui with no success. And I don't think this is a file permission issue because I can access http://<my-private-ip>/wms-ui just fine.
Why am I getting this 404 error? I'm a bit new to NGINX, so I'd appreciate more elaborated explanations.

The index directive applies to URLs that point to directories, and will return the indicated file within that directory if it exists. So /wms-ui/some-other-page should return /var/www/<my-private-ip>/html/wms-ui/some-other-page/index.html (if it exists).

@RichardSmith I see what you're saying now. I misinterpreted what alias was supposed to do.

I had misinterpreted what alias was supposed to do, so I resorted to using root with a try_files directive:
location /wms-ui {
    root /var/www/<my-private-ip>/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wms-ui/index.html;
}       

But this broke requests for .js files, so I added:
location ~ ^/wms-ui.*\.js$ {    
    root /var/www/<my-private-ip>/html;
    index index.js;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wms-ui/index.js;
}

This works because regex matches (location ~ <regex>) take precedence over prefix matches (location <prefix>).
Then I realized /var/www/<my-private-ip>/html/wms-ui wasn't making a lot of sense semantically because I'm serving more than just HTML files there, so I moved all application files to /var/www/<my-private-ip>/wms-ui and removed /html from all root directives.
This solution isn't exactly clean and I'm open to suggestions, but it's the best I could come up with right now.
Update
The reason my JS files were breaking is that my built HTML file had a relative src attribute on my script tag (<script src="index.js" />). I set up my tooling to use /wms-ui as the base URL, turning the src attribute into src=/wms-ui/index.js. I then removed the location ~ ^/wms-ui.*\.js$ block from my NGINX site configuration file.
